# Plotly x-axis dates are displayed as the date plus one day

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly to create a stacked bar chart, with each bar representing a quarter end date. The data is pulled into a dataframe via SQL and the dates are parsed in the read_sql statement.

When graphing the dates on the x-axis are displayed as 10/01 instead of 9/30, 4/1 instead of 3/31, etc.

Any idea how I can just display the dates correctly?

Here's a sample

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df.groupby('dt_quarter').head(10), x='dt_quarter', y="amount", color="name", title="Stack Bar Test")
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title_text = 'Amount ($)',xaxis_title_text='Date', legend_title_text='Sector', legend_traceorder='reversed')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you some sample data and the code you are using to generate the plot?

Comment: If you could somehow give us some sample code and data we can help you better. My only idea otherwise is to add `-1`  before displaying. Your data may start at a different index than the lib plotting the graph

Comment: @MaximilianPeters  added some code

Comment: @TheOtterlord added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a new column in my dataframe that displays the date in 'QXYYYY' format (e.g. Q42020, etc.). I then used that as my x axis and it works fine.

For creating the new column:

```
alldata['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(alldata.dt_quarter, freq='Q').astype('str')
```